# Why isn't my modal working?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement a modal on my website http://mattydb.com/ but when I click on the changelog nothing pops up.

Could someone suggest a way to fix this?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-modal-sm">Changelog</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Initial Release</p>
            <ul>
                <li> Added hate paragraph </li>
                <li> Added "random" picture </li>
                <li> Added Twitter feed </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post your code. Dont expect from us to inspect your site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got an error in your page which says:

```
Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery
```

So it seems you haven't add jQuery to your page, you can add it to your page like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you should add it before bootstrap script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still not working for me even after adding jQuery

Comment: @akkatracker: add it to your site, allows me to test it.

Comment: I've updated it Mehran.

Comment: @akkatracker: you should add it before bootstrap script.

Comment: @akkatracker: you're welcome that's why we are here. Cheers :)